# How to use result from barcodescanner somewhere else?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

So i have a barcodescan button, I want to press it and scan an item, then retrieve the barcode and use the retrieved barcode in another button (this will send an api request with the barcode), how would i go about this?

Would love if someone could point me in the right direction, cant seem to find any answers online (probably searching for the wrong thing).

Thanks in advance!

This is partially my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import QRCodeReader
import Alamofire




class NewViewController: UIViewController, QRCodeReaderViewControllerDelegate {
    
    lazy var readerVC: QRCodeReaderViewController = {
    let builder = QRCodeReaderViewControllerBuilder {
    //change object to scan and the initial position of the camera
        $0.reader = QRCodeReader(metadataObjectTypes: [.qr, .ean13], captureDevicePosition: .back)

    // Configure the view controller (optional)
    $0.showTorchButton = true
    $0.showSwitchCameraButton = false
    $0.showCancelButton = true
    $0.showOverlayView = true //shows the square area of the QRCode Scanner
        $0.rectOfInterest = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        
        //$0.rectOfInterest = CGRect(x: 0.12, y: 0.3, width: 0.8, height: 0.6)
    }
    return QRCodeReaderViewController(builder: builder)
    }()
    

    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        readerVC.delegate = self
    
    }
    
    func reader(_ reader: QRCodeReaderViewController, didScanResult result: QRCodeReaderResult) {
    //code to be added
        reader.stopScanning()
        print(result)
        print(result.value) //I WANT TO USE THIS RESULT SOMEWHERE ELSE //ANOTHER BUTTON
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func readerDidCancel(_ reader: QRCodeReaderViewController) {
    //code to be added
        reader.stopScanning()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
    
        @IBAction func BARCODESCANNER(_ sender: UIButton) {

            readerVC.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
            self.present(readerVC, animated: true)

           //THIS BUTTON OPENS THE BARCODE SCANNER AND RETRIEVES RESULT IN THE "func reader" ABOVE
        
    }
    

    
    @IBAction func ANOTHERBUTTON(_ sender: Any) {
        
        // I WANT TO USE THE RETRIEVED BARCODE HERE WITH MORE CODE FOR AN API REQUEST
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty much there. What's missing here is an extra variable for you to store the barcode scan result in.

On your view controller add something like:
`private var barcode: String? = nil`

It can be assigned a value when you get a result in `reader(_: QRCodeReaderViewController, didScanResult: QRCodeReaderResult)`.

Now because `barcode` is added as an optional property, in your `ANOTHERBUTTON` function, you can easily ensure that a barcode value is set before the function does anything by using a `guard`.

So that would look something like:

```
@IBAction func ANOTHERBUTTON(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let barcode = barcode else { return }
    // ... your code using the barcode goes here
}
```

You should now be able to continue building your view.

Comment: Jesus christ, i've been scratching my head for ages and the answer was so simple. You have no idea how thankful i am, this code will help alot of people do their job in a much simpler way! :)